# Is it possible to use Lazy loading for more than just images and videos?

Tags: lazy-loading

I'm trying to streamline my employers website using lazy loading, but every tutorial I've come across only specifies images and / or videos. Is it possible to use lazy loading on a whole div block which may contain text, buttons and images etc? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It certainly possible to load HTML elements like a div lazily. You could use some library to track the viewport and as soon as an element enters the viewport you do an AJAX request to get and render the div.
But I doubt that it is worth the effort. Text is usually not the issue when it comes to optimizing performance. I would recommend that you focus on lazyloading the images and videos. Have a look at these resources: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/get-started/